# imagick error converting pdf to png: Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/magick-bpkD9zy7': @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/663

Tags: php, imagick

I need to convert multipage PDFs to series of PNGs that will be displayed in a browser.

This code works:

```
$images = new imagick();
$images->readimage($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
$images->setformat('png');

    foreach ($images as $pageNumber => $image) {
       //Save individual images 
     }
```

But it generates PNGs that are of such poor quality that they are almost unreadable.

This code:

```
$images = new imagick();
$images->setresolution(1024,0);
$images->readimage($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
$images->setformat('png');

    foreach ($images as $pageNumber => $image) {
       //Save individual images 
     }
```

Generates the following error at readimage():

```
Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/magick-bpkD9zy7': @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/663
```

I need to be able to rasterize the PDF at a higher resolution than the imagick default to get good enough quality to be able to read the PNGs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - BELOW IS THE SOLUTION - THANKS TO SITES DONE RIGHT

```
$images = new imagick();
$images->setimageunits(RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$images->setresolution(150,150);
$images->readimage($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
$images->setformat('png');

    foreach ($images as $pageNumber => $image) {
       //Save individual images 
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
$images->setresolution
```

sets the density of the image. Instead of trying 1024,0 (which would be like using *convert -density 1024x0*), try setting the density to something like 200x200.

Then use http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageunits.php

```
$images->setImageUnits
```

to set the units of that resolution (to something like "PixelsPerInch"). That should properly set the image's clarity.

Comment: Here's the command I wrote for use in one of my projects to convert a PDF to a set of images. `convert -colorspace rgb -units PixelsPerInch -density 200x200  -resize 768x1024 -quality 90 my_pdf_file.pdf my_images_output.jpg'` I suppose it could be run like that in PHP if you used the exec function. Also note, as you can see I am creating JPG's, so for PNG's it would have to be revised a bit!

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but I am unable to use it. The problem I am having is that I get an error described above if I set _any_ parameters before I read the PDF

Comment: Sites Done Right - I understand what you are saying now! I was setting the PixelsPerInch to 1024 and that that was causing me to run out space in my temp directory.